# Remote validation impedindo edição de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estou utilizando o remote validation para impedir e-mails repetidos no banco de dados, o que funciona bem, quando eu faço algum cadastro. O problema é que o remote não aceita o valor original do cadastro, e não me permite salvar as alterações feitas nos outros campos. Vi uma possível solução dizendo para passar o ID em uma caixa de texto escondida, mas também não funcionou.

Minha Action de edição.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Editar(Usuarios usuario) 
    {

        ViewBag.CountryList = p.GetCountries();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(usuario);
    }
```

Método que verifica o Email.

```
public JsonResult validaEmail(string email)
        {
            return Json(!db.Usuarios.Any(u => u.Email == email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
[Display(Name = "E-mail")]
[Remote("validaEmail", "Validar",AreaReference.UseRoot,ErrorMessage = "E-mail já existente. Por favor, utilize outro E-mail")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Mostra como você faz a chamada no cliente para validar o email.

Comment: Editei. Confere se é isso mesmo, por favor.

Comment: Testa ai e me fala se o remote validation está passando o id. Sds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem que passar o *id* mesmo senão você não vai conseguir alterar o objeto. Vai ficar algo assim:

```
public JsonResult validaEmail(string email, int id)
{
    return Json(!db.Usuarios.Any(u => u.Email == email && i.Id != id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Acho que isso resolve:

```
[Remote("validaEmail", "Validar", AdditionalFields = "Id", AreaReference.UseRoot,ErrorMessage = "E-mail já existente. Por favor, utilize outro E-mail")]
```

Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou assim (pode ver o tutorial e baixar o projeto zipado em http://blogdoquintal.net/2015/01/06/fazendo-validacao-ajax-no-servidor-com-asp-net-mvc/

**HomeController** (sempre vai retornar false para os testes):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult EmailDisponivel(int? Id, string email)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Campo obrigatório")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Email inválido")]
    [Remote("EmailDisponivel", "Home", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "E-mail já existente. Por favor, utilize outro E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**View** (o codigo da view por ter html vai ficar todo esquisito mas é mais ou menos isso:

```
@model ValidacaoRemota.Models.Usuario

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

### Index

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Usuario</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Então, ele parou de verificar o campo Email, mas ainda assim não consigo salvar as edições.

Comment: Na verdade, não chega nem a dar o post. Vou te adicionar.

Comment: vou tentar fazer um projeto aqui e te envio

Comment: pra que esse  AreaReference.UseRoot? Não conheço.

Comment: Aqui funcionou legal. vou te passar os itens do projeto

Comment: Olha ai. Só tirei esse AreaReference.UseRoot. Vou criar um tutorial no meu blog e te mando o link. Lá eu coloco o projeto para download.